# Finding the variance without complete data

Tags: probability

Suppose the salaries of being an alien is normally distributed. Furthermore, 25% earn less than 50,000 galactic credit (GC) and 25% earn more than 150,000 GC. How can I find or approximate the variance?

I know the equation of normally distribution and all the other elements except for this. 
$$f(x) = \frac{1}{\sigma \sqrt{2 \pi}}e^{-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2 \sigma}}$$
My ultimate goal is to approximate the fraction that earn less than 55,000 GC and between 125,000 GC and 150,000 GC.
I just started learning probability, so I am not very good at it.

Comment: Hint: From tables, $\Pr(Z\le z)=0.75$ at $z\approx 0.675$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given unknown $\mu$ and $\sigma$ you can compare your distribution to a standard normal distribution via:
$$z=\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}$$
From a standard distribution table $Pr(Z\leq z)=0.75$ gives $z\approx0.675$ and $Pr(Z\leq z)=0.25$ gives $z\approx-0.675$ so you get two equations:

$$0.675=\frac{150000-\mu}{\sigma}$$
and
$$-0.675=\frac{50000-\mu}{\sigma}$$
then just solve simultaneously.